# Get the end date for an ISO week number in Google Data studio/Looker Studio

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I google data studio, I have a field called week that contains the week number the value is string 'Week 2' for example. How can I extract the last day of the week based on the week number. In this case I want to get 2023-01-14 which is the last day of week 2?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DS6Dt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works:

DATEtime_ADD(DATEtime_TRUNC(DATEtime_ADD(DATEtime_TRUNC(date, WEEK), INTERVAL (week-1) * 1 DAY), WEEK), INTERVAL 6 DAY)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [last_day](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#last_day) function?

I would build from the using the date using last_day, because from the week number it would require a bit more code.

```sql
SELECT *, 
  LAST_DAY(today, WEEK) AS last_day_of_week, 
  EXTRACT(WEEK FROM today) AS week_number

FROM (SELECT CURRENT_DATE() AS today)
```

But if you need to go with just the week number, I recommend taking a look into this other question [How to create date based on year, week number and day in bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58000860/how-to-create-date-based-on-year-week-number-and-day-in-bigquery) .

Comment: I already have the week number in Looker Studio. I want to extract the last date of each week's number based on the pre-calculated field Week.